# How to solve below code Attempt to de-reference a NULL Object Error

Tags: visualforce

Shoeing error msg :

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!showParticipant}' in page rendercust: Class.Participant.showParticipant: line 25, column 1

Class.Participant.showParticipant: line 25, column 1
```

---

```
public with sharing class Participant {

    public Participant__c participant{get;set;} 
    public Boolean showFlag{get;set;}


   public Participant(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      // Participant__C participant=new Participant__C();

     }

    public Participant(){

     participant=new Participant__C();
     participant = [select id,name,Contact_Info__c,Identity_Number__c,Medical_Disclosure__c,
                        PAN_Number__c,Passport_Number__c,
                        AdharCard_Number__c,Status__c,T_Shirt_Size__c
                        FROM Participant__c];

                     showFlag = false;   
    }


    public void showParticipant(){
        if( participant.Status__c == 'Participant'){

            showFlag = true;
        }else{
            showFlag = false;
        }
        }

    public pageReference save() {
        showParticipant();
        Participant__c participant2 = NeW Participant__c ();

        participant2.Name = participant.Name; 
        participant2.Contact_Info__c = participant.Contact_Info__c;
        participant2.Passport_Number__c = participant.Passport_Number__c;
        participant2.T_Shirt_Size__c = participant.T_Shirt_Size__c;
        participant2.Identity_Number__c = participant.Identity_Number__c;
        participant2.PAN_Number__c = participant.PAN_Number__c;
        participant2.AdharCard_Number__c =participant.AdharCard_Number__c;
        participant2.Status__c = participant.Status__c;
        participant2.Medical_Disclosure__c = participant.Medical_Disclosure__c;
        insert participant2;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is line 25. Probably because you never call participant and this never instantiate the participant property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you commented out your initialization of `participant` in your constructor that takes a `StandardController` as a parameter.  That method should probably be changed to:

```
public Participant(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    participant = (Participant__c)controller.getRecord();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say but was editing the question :p

Comment: @sfdcfox Internet Points are a cutthroat competition.

Comment: lol, contrariwise, I'm glad I'm not the only one answering questions. I always look forward to your answers. ... Partly, I guess, since we share the same name, but that's just because Brians are awesome.